# Can't open Market App from my Application

Tags: android, android-intent, google-play

I'm trying to open market app from my app using:

```
Intent i = new Intent("Intent.ACTION_VIEW");
i.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.compamy.app"));
startActivity(i);
```

But I have *No Activity Found* Error. I am using real device and I have market installed. 
So my question is: What can be done here?Thanks.

Comment: `Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);` w/o `"`. The value of that constant is `"android.intent.action.VIEW"`

Answer (score 4):

The only problem here is what zapl pointed out in the comments ("" around the action). The documentation (http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html) clearly states how to use this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.example.android"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

**official documantation link:**

http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html#marketintent

Opening the app details page from your Android app

To open the Google Play details page from your application, create an intent with the ACTION_VIEW action and include a data URI in this format:

> market://details?id=

For example, here's how you can create an intent and open an application's details page in Google Play:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.example.android"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.compamy.app");

Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);

startActivity(i);
```